# Sharing iTunes account

Tags: home-sharing

My husband and I share the same iTunes account but when we sync our iPhones to the same account, we can no longer text each other.

I've tried starting my own account in which the iTunes will sync but all of my contacts and calendar events are no longer on my phone.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

Under Settings -> Messages, check "Receive At" - you are probably both using the same Apple ID for messages.  One of you will need to setup a separate Apple ID to use for Messages.  You should be able to do this while continuing to share the same iTunes account.

Comment: In addition to setting up a new Apple ID, you can also choose to receive messages at your phone number (though this introduces complications if you want to *also* use Messages on the iPad or the upcoming OS X app).